# How to find the orthonormal basis for these three signals

Tags: signal-analysis, orthornormal

I've been given these signals:

$$S1(t) = 1$$

$$S2(t) = t$$

$$S3(t) = t^2$$

I have to find 3 basis functions using Gram - Schmidt algorithm on the interval $|t| \le 1$. Now, I know the procedure and formulas but I am not sure how to treat $|t| \le 1$. Will it only affect the limits of the integral?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will it only affect the limits of the integral?

Yes.